# If $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$ is $L^2$-differentiable, then $Df \in L^1 \cap L^2$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Working with the definition that $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is $L^2$-differentiable with $L^2$-derivative $Df$ if
$$ \frac{\|\tau_hf-f-hDf\|_2}{h} \to 0 \text{ as } h \to 0 $$
(where $\tau_h(x) = f(x+h)$), I want to try and show that

> If $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$ is $L^2$-differentiable, then $Df \in L^1 \cap L^2$.

Showing that $Df \in L^2$ is immediate from the definition; however, I'm unsure on how to get that $Df \in L_1$. I've tried arguing from density of continuous compactly supported functions (for which $Df \in L^2 \implies Df \in L^1$ by Jensen's inequality), but to no avail.

Comment: As indicated in my answer below, I am very convinced that your claim is false. So: What makes you believe that this should be true? Did you find this statement somewhere?

Comment: @PhoemueX It's more of a 'hope', to be honest - I'm trying to prove that if $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$, then $\xi \hat{f} \in L^2$. Now, if $Df$ has a FT, the result follows straightforwardly; however we only defined the FT for $L^1$ functions. I suppose one could maybe approximate $Df$ by convolutions with Gaussians to get around this, but I'd have to have a look. I'm on my mobile ATM, but I'll work through your potential counterexample ASAP.

Comment: Why you are trying to show is also false. Take $f =\chi_[-1,1]$, then $\hat{f}$ is something like $\sin(\xi)/\xi $, so that $\xi \hat{f}(\xi)=\sin(\xi)$ lies in no $L^p$ space with $p<\infty$, although $f$ is in every $L^p$ space.

Comment: @PhoemueX Apologies - I forgot to add that $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$ is $L^2$ differentiable also in my comment above, in which case I believe I know how to deal with this. Regardless, I'm convinced you've shown my original claim/hope to be false, so many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that what you are trying to prove is true.

Consider e.g.

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \sin(x^2) \text{ for large } x,
$$
i.e. truncate $f$ somehow near the origin.

We then have $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$ with

$$
f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^3} \cdot \sin(x^2) + \frac{2}{x} \cdot \cos(x^2).
$$

We have $f' \in L^2$, but (as shown below) $f' \notin L^1$.

Even with your definition of differentiability, I am convinced that $f$ is $L^2$-differentiable with $L^2$-derivative $f' \in L^2 \setminus L^1$.

EDIT: Ok, here is a proof that $f' \notin L^1$. First of all, we have $\frac{1}{x^3} \cdot \sin(x^2) \in L^1 ((1,\infty))$ (and we are considering everything away from the origin), so that $f' \notin L^1$ is equivalent to $\frac{2}{x} \cdot \cos(x^2) \notin L^1$. But the subsitution $\omega =x^2$ yields

$$
\int_1^\infty \bigg| \frac{2}{x} \cdot \cos(x^2) \bigg| \, dx = \int_1^\infty \bigg| \frac{\cos(\omega)}{\omega} \bigg| \, d\omega = \infty,
$$
because of $|\cos(\omega)| \geq 1/2$ on $(-\epsilon, \epsilon) + 2\pi \Bbb{Z}$, which easily implies that the integral diverges.

Comment: @Tomás: I added a proof of $f' \notin L^1$. This still leaves the verification that $f$ is differentiable **in the sense of the question**.

Comment: Yes it is differentiable in that sense. As long that $u\in C^1$ and $u,u'\in L^2$, you can conclude that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u(x+h)-u(x)-hu'(x)|^2dx\le h^2\int_0^1\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u'(x+sh)-u'(x)|^2dxds.$$ Now one can use the continuity of the translation operator in $L^2$.